# Handoff url from laptop to mobile?

Tags: iphone, safari, firefox, web-browser

I use Firefox on Mac and Safari on iOS. Whenever I open Safari on my phone I notice an icon for Firefox with a mobile symbol appearing in my dock on Mac and if I click it, whichever URL I was on on Safari will open up on my Mac in Firefox.

I would like the reverse of this. I want to send the current article that I'm reading to my phone to read it later when I'm out.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some instructions from the [iPhone User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/hand-off-tasks-between-devices-iphcec5d0a9d/ios)

**Hand off from another device to your iPhone**

1. Open the [App Switcher](https://support.apple.com/guide/iphone/aside/iph956b628e2/17.0/ios/17.0) on iPhone. The Handoff icon of the app you’re using on your other device appears at the bottom of the iPhone screen.
2. Tap the Handoff icon to continue working in the app.